# Detect eye direction without libraries

Tags: java, image-processing

I am searching for some days already a tutorial or some documents to start this task. I need to detect eye direction in Java from a video (or, for start, from a Image). I am not allowed to use any libraries or api, so I have to write the program line by line.
If anyone knows how should I start, because I don't have a clue. All tutorials I've found are based on openCV or some librari.
I don't request code, but I would be grateful if someone could give me a starting point and some guideline, which filter I should make, what algoritms should I use to detect what and when. Thank for help:)

PS: Also the algorithm must be fast, so it could detect eyes in real time on a android device. Recursive searching could be laggy.

Comment: *"because I don't have a clue"*  Uh-oh..  'Questions must demonstrate a *minimal understanding* of the problem'..

Comment: Is just an expression, actually I know I should make a filter to increase contrast, make it white and black, and find somehow what I am looking for. But thanks for help.

Comment: *"Is just an expression,"*  Be more careful with the expressions you toss about in future.  But it makes little difference, since I had a ***range*** of possible close reasons.  That was simply 'top of the list'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(This should really be a comment, but it is too long so I'm posting it as an answer.)*

There is no easy answer to this question, as it is very broad. You are basically asking whether or not there is a "default" or "best" way to do eye gaze detection. To the best of my knowledge, there is not. In addition, it is unclear what hardware you are working with. Having high-speed cameras and controlled lighting is very different to say having just a webcam.

So here is how I would suggest approaching the problem:

1. Read up on research papers that do eye gaze detection. Search terms could include "eye gaze detection", "eye tracking" etc.
2. If you don't understand parts of the papers, check the references and read up on the prerequisites. You can also use books or lecture slides for this.
3. Implement a reference implementation using a tool such as Matlab or any programming language using libraries that do the basics for you (e.g. OpenCV, a library to do machine learning if needed, etc.). This enables you to rapidly try different things with minimal changes required while you are testing your approaches.
4. Only then implement the actual processing in Java. Getting the low-level algorithms exactly right (and fast) can be tricky, and you will be glad to have a reference implementation to compare your results to.

Comment: Thank you, I already search for eye tracking, I will try to do as you suggested me. You try to say I should make it work with some libraries and after that write my own function? Sounds like some extra work (understanding what is going on in those libraries). I will run this program on Samsung s3 or nexus 4, using the front camera (720p).

Comment: Well it is up to you of course. However I doubt you will get far without at least being able to check if what you are doing is correct. And you don't need to understand exactly what the libraries are doing until the final step, when you implement the low-level stuff yourself. BTW: You can run OpenCV on Android, and it as native code it is going to be much faster than anything you write in Java.

Comment: I know OpenCV is native code but I am not allowed to use if, Thank you